# Merging point objects that are overlapping without creating a new shapefile and losing data?

Tags: qgis, mmqgis

I managed to join 2 Point shapefiles together using MMQGIS by converting my shapefiles form multi point to point and then joining them.

But now there are double points and even more then there need to be. So some points are overlapping, which is a mistake on my part I should have couple attributes based on location but that was not actually possible.

Now how do I merge the "points" that are actually overlapping, without creating a new shapefile and losing the data.

Comment: Just for the next time, you can also simply start the edeting mode of a point layer, press strg + a (to selct all points), press strg + c (to copy), switch to your other point layer, start edeting mode as well, press strg + v (to paste). Now all points are in the same layer. Save and commit changes.

Comment: @ThunderSpark: Did you try the geometry checker plugin? (http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_geometry_checker.html)
There is an option to check for duplicates.

Comment: Miron's suggestion helped us a lot. Thank you. Also Thanks to Jason for the suggestion.